# Video files are not opening for sample applications in Info Sphere Streams

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, gpu, ibm-streams

I am new to IBM Info Sphere Streams, I read an article which says IBM Info Sphere streams is capable of doing Image processing. After some research I got to know that, we have to install OpenCV and FFMpeg lybraries with its dependecies. I have installed all of them and tried sample applications. I can run applications which contains Images as input, but when it comes to processing with videos it's not working. I am unable to use x11viewer operator as well. I am getting the following error while working with sample videos.

```
(Streams com.ibm.streamsx.opencv::X11Viewer operator:7889): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
28 Feb 2017 14:00:34.672 [7889] ERROR #splapptrc,J[0],P[0],vid0,spl_pe M[PEImpl.cpp:process:1270]  - CDISR5079E: An exception occurred during the processing of the processing element. The error is: Unable to open camera {0}.
```

I did not install any GPU device drivers here but when I used the following commands I am getting results like below,

```
[streamsadmin@streamsqse output]$ lspci | grep VGA
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter

[streamsadmin@streamsqse output]$ find /dev -group video
/dev/fb0
/dev/dri/card0
/dev/dri/renderD128
/dev/dri/controlD64
/dev/agpgart
```

and

```
glxinfo | grep -i vendor
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc
```

My doubt here is, whether I have installed GPU Drivers properly or do I need to install them again? Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

And I am unable to open those videos by using any player as well.

Comment: The error message says "Unable to open camera". Are you trying to run a sample application that ingests live video from a camera? If so, does your real machine have a camera? If so, have you attached the camera to your virtual machine?

Comment: Thanks for replying back to me, This Error message is for the Sample application having Camera but when I am trying sample application which is having video file as input then it is saying unable to open Video file.

Answer (score 0):

Would have like to added a comment asking about the code, error and location of the video file but I am a newbie here and can't comment.

Assuming the 'unable to open Video file' error indicates 'file not found' it means the file is not in the correct location in the SAB file created.  Getting this right means understanding the data-directory, something that can trip up folks new to streams.

Assuming you are using the video_stream.spl sample and the file parameter is unchanged: 
   file: "../sample_faces5.mpg";
then the file needs to be in the directory above your data-directory when you compile.

The data directory can be specified when you compile the SPL or at submit time.  I prefer specifying it at compile time.   See this page:
  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSCRJU_4.2.0/com.ibm.streams.dev.doc/doc/appdirlayout.html

Note that the MAKEFILE specifies DATA_DIR = data
You would need to create the directory 'data' in your application directory then put the video file in the application directory above it.  Personally I put my data files in the 'data' directory and specify dot

```
 file: "./sample_faces5.mpg";
```

Hope my guesses are correct and this helps.

Comment: Hi Stanley Thanks for replying back to me. I can able to run sample applications having images but when it comes to process video files the above mentioned error coming. I have found that while researching, we need to have licensed FFMpeg libraries inorder to do processing on video files. Is it true or we need to enable any other FFMPeg libraries for enabling the video codecs?